# How to save encrypted String in Firebase with Dart Flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm developing a password manager app in flutter to store the passwords.

Now I want to save all data to firestore, but the problem is here that all data is stored as encrypted text or in non-readable form, I have used the [encypt](https://pub.dev/packages/encrypt) plugin to encrypt the data. I have 4 fields there

- _id
- title
- username
- password

All field data is saved in an encrypted format but I want to save the `title` value as decrypted text or in a readable form.

I have tried to change `final encryptedText = Encrypt.instance.encryptOrDecryptText(title.text, true);` to `final encryptedText = Encrypt.instance.encryptOrDecryptText(title.text, false);` but it occures error in database while saving.

I'm sharing my code for your reference.

**add_password.dart**

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_application_1/db/pass_db.dart';
import 'package:flutter_application_1/encrypter/encrypter.dart';
import 'package:flutter_application_1/model/pass_model.dart';

class AddTask extends StatefulWidget {
  late Function refershPasswords;

  AddTask({Key? key, required this.refershPasswords}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _AddTaskState createState() => _AddTaskState();
}

class _AddTaskState extends State<AddTask> {
  TextEditingController title = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController username = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController password = TextEditingController();

  late List<Password> passwords;
  bool isLoading = false;
  String status = '';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    refreshNotes();
  }

  Future refreshNotes() async {
    setState(() => isLoading = true);
    passwords = await PasswordDatabase.instance.readAllNotes();
    setState(() => isLoading = false);
  }

  Future<void> _uploadPassToFire(List<Password> passwords) async {
    for (Password password in passwords) {
      await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('Passwords List')
          .doc()
          .set(password.toJson());
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: const Color(0xff151922),
        appBar: AppBar(
          elevation: 0.0,
          backgroundColor: const Color(0xff151922),
          centerTitle: false,
          title: const Text(
            'Add New Password',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          ),
          leading: IconButton(
            onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
            icon: const Icon(
              Icons.arrow_back_ios_new_rounded,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          ),
          systemOverlayStyle: SystemUiOverlayStyle.light,
        ),
        body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 0.0, 20.0, 0.0),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              const Text(
                'Website Name',
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 14.0,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 5.0,
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 75.0,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 40.0,
                child: TextFormField(
                  style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  cursorColor: Colors.white,
                  maxLength: 60,
                  controller: title,
                  onFieldSubmitted: (value) {
                    title.text = value;
                  },
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: 'Google',
                    hintStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                    focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                      borderSide:
                          const BorderSide(color: Colors.white, width: 2.0),
                    ),
                    enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                      borderSide: const BorderSide(
                        color: Colors.white10,
                        width: 2.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                    counterStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                    prefixIcon: const Icon(
                      Icons.title,
                      size: 24,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0)),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 10.0,
              ),
              const Text(
                'Username/Email',
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 14.0,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 5.0,
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 75.0,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 40.0,
                child: TextFormField(
                  style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  maxLength: 60,
                  controller: username,
                  onFieldSubmitted: (value) {
                    username.text = value;
                  },
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: 'mkmandawar',
                    hintStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                    focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                      borderSide:
                          const BorderSide(color: Colors.white, width: 2.0),
                    ),
                    enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                      borderSide: const BorderSide(
                        color: Colors.white10,
                        width: 2.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                    counterStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                    prefixIcon: const Icon(
                      Icons.email_rounded,
                      size: 24,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0)),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 10.0,
              ),
              const Text(
                'Password',
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 14.0,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 5.0,
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 75.0,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 40.0,
                child: TextFormField(
                  obscureText: true,
                  style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  maxLength: 60,
                  controller: password,
                  onFieldSubmitted: (value) {
                    password.text = value;
                  },
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: 'PassWord@123',
                    hintStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                    focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                      borderSide:
                          const BorderSide(color: Colors.white, width: 2.0),
                    ),
                    enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                      borderSide: const BorderSide(
                        color: Colors.white10,
                        width: 2.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                    prefixIcon: const Icon(
                      Icons.vpn_key,
                      size: 24,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    counterStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                    fillColor: Colors.white,
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0)),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 20.0,
              ),
              GestureDetector(
                onTap: () async {
                  if (title.text == '' &&
                      username.text == '' &&
                      password.text == '') {
                    setState(() {
                      status = "All Fields Can't Be Empty";
                    });
                  } else if (title.text == '' || password.text == '') {
                    setState(() {
                      status = "Title And Password Are Compulsory";
                    });
                  } else {
                    final encryptedText = Encrypt.instance
                        .encryptOrDecryptText(title.text, true);
                    final encryptedUsername = Encrypt.instance
                        .encryptOrDecryptText(username.text, true);
                    final encryptedPassword = Encrypt.instance
                        .encryptOrDecryptText(password.text, true);

                    var passwordss = Password(
                        title: encryptedText,
                        username: encryptedUsername,
                        password: encryptedPassword);
                    PasswordDatabase.instance.create(passwordss);
                    widget.refershPasswords();
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  }
                  _uploadPassToFire(passwords);
                },
                child: Container(
                  height: 60.0,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 50.0,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: const Color(0xff14279B),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0)),
                  child: const Center(
                    child: Text(
                      'Save Password',
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 24.0,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 5.0,
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    status,
                    style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16.0),
                  ),
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

**pass_model.dart**

```
const String tableNotes = 'passwords';

class PasswordFields {
  static final List<String> values = [
    /// Add all fields
    id, title, username, password
  ];

  static const String id = '_id';
  static const String title = 'title';
  static const String username = 'description';
  static const String password = 'password';
}

class Password {
  final int? id;
  final String title;
  final String username;
  final String password;

  const Password({
    this.id,
    required this.title,
    required this.username,
    required this.password,
  });

  Password copy({
    int? id,
    String? title,
    String? username,
    String? password,
  }) =>
      Password(
        id: id ?? this.id,
        title: title ?? this.title,
        username: username ?? this.username,
        password: password ?? this.password,
      );

  static Password fromJson(Map<String, Object?> json) => Password(
        id: json[PasswordFields.id] as int?,
        title: json[PasswordFields.title] as String,
        username: json[PasswordFields.username] as String,
        password: json[PasswordFields.password] as String,
      );

  Map<String, Object?> toJson() => {
        PasswordFields.id: id,
        PasswordFields.title: title,
        PasswordFields.username: username,
        PasswordFields.password: password
      };
}
```

**encrypter.dart**

```
import 'package:encrypt/encrypt.dart' as encrypt;

class Encrypt {
  static final Encrypt instance = Encrypt._init();

  Encrypt._init();

  String encryptOrDecryptText(String value, isEncrypt) {
    final key = encrypt.Key.fromLength(32);
    final iv = encrypt.IV.fromLength(8);
    final encrypter = encrypt.Encrypter(encrypt.Salsa20(key));

    if (isEncrypt == true) {
      final encrypted = encrypter.encrypt(value, iv: iv);
      return encrypted.base64;
    } else {
      final decrypted =
          encrypter.decrypt(encrypt.Encrypted.from64(value), iv: iv);
      return decrypted;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: please add the error message also

Comment: Why don't you DECRYPT the title-field before saving the dataset to firebase ?

Comment: @SubairK when I try this I'm getting this `E/flutter (13200): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Invalid length, must be multiple of four (at character 6)` and some it store invalid characters.

Comment: @MichaelFehr I already try my best, can you help